# How to setup tf for real robot?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, tf-broadcaster, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done a complete navigation stack simulation with my robot model using URDF and gazebo, where i have added tf & jointstate plugin in urdf file. Now I have assembled my robot with the required hardware (actuators and sensors), so how to setup tf for my real robot.

Please post the steps involved and direct me to the resources to learn or some existing packages.

PS: I have done tf tutorials in ROS navigation stack but i cant figure out how to do it for complete robot mobile robot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229884/how-to-setup-tf-for-real-robot?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-11-03**:
Closing this as it has been answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to look at the [TF Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials). #1 for both C++ and Python is setting up a transform broadcaster.

[EDIT]

Been a few months :P. You can use the URDF model to publish the transforms. Using the  tag allows you to enter the parent ID, child ID, and origin transforms between links.

If you want to make a quick tranform tree though, [here](https://github.com/mars-uoit/omnimaxbot/blob/master/omnimaxbot_description/src/tf_broadcaster.cpp) is the transform broadcaster I made for a robot while working on my MASc. Making the transform tree doesn't give you a visual, but it does provide the transforms between parts.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-03-23**:
Should i build the broadcaster code for my complete robot or i can use my URDF to publish the tf?

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-03-23**:
I've always built the tf broadcaster for my robots, so I am not sure if the URDF model can publish the tf or not

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-08-27**:
Can you pls share a tf node of a robot. The tutorials have only the broadcaster and listener.